# Tracking Emails containing plain text in C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, user-tracking

I want to track an email containing only plain text in gmail or yahoo.I got the solutions in which i have to insert the image to track it.So is there any way to track the email only containing plain text in gmail or yahoo using c#?

Comment: You question seems improper. How are you supposed to insert an image to track a plain text? Please provide necessary links that support your Research and Development, so that it would be helpful for someone to help you in answering your expectations.

Answer (score 2):

Tracking email opens in plain text emails (without the recipient clicking on a link) is not possible.

See https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2007/01/all-about-email-open-rates/ .

> So if you are sending text-only emails, there is no way to record open
>   rates (the exception is if they actually click a link).

Answer (score 2):

Tracking works by letting the reader's browser or mail client send an HTTP request to a server which does the tracking.

If you have a plaintext email, you can't include any elements (like an image) that result in an HTTP request.

So: no.